# Is Everything Declared as Class must be an NSObject?

Tags: core-data, xcode4.5

I make a category like this:

```
@interface NSObject (defaultSelector)
+(NSString *) defaultSelector;
-(NSString *)defaultSelector;
@end
```

Then, I used it like this:

```
-(void)prefetchShortcutWithTable: (Class) someNSManagedObjectClass forInputArray: (NSArray *) inputArray withDictCache: (NSMutableDictionary *) dictToSave
{
    NSString * attribute = [someNSManagedObjectClass defaultSelector];
    [self prefetchShortcutWithTable:NSStringFromClass(someNSManagedObjectClass) forAttribute:attribute forInputArray:inputArray withDictCache:dictToSave];
}
```

The whole thing works. However, how does the compiler knows that someNSManagedObjectClass will be a subclass of an NSObject?

In fact, how do I rewrite the function so that     `-(void)prefetchShortcutWithTable: (Class) someNSManagedObjectClass forInputArray: (NSArray *) inputArray withDictCache: (NSMutableDictionary *) dictToSave` only accept subclasses of NSManagedObject?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSObject` is the base class of any `someNSManagedObjectClass` or `anyOtherClass` you are going to make.

Comment: Can you show me documentation? Not everything is descendant of NSObject.

Comment: @SharenEayrs: The first line in the NSManagedObject Class Reference is: "Inherits from NSObject". - NSObject is the root class of most Objective-C class hierarchies. The only exception that I know is `NSProxy`.

Comment: Yeah.Maybe `anyOtherClass` part was exaggerated, still `NSObject` is the root class of most of the classes in Objective - C hierarchy and definitely for `someNSManagedObjectClass`. You might want to check out `NSManagedObject` Class's reference documents. For `NSObject` class here it is[link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: What about if I want to specify that someNSManagedObjectClass must be a descendant of NSManagedObject?

Comment: In the `.h` file, where you declare the class, you use this statement `@interface someClass : SomeClass` to tell the complier which class it  inherits. You can tell `someClass` to be descendant of any class even if you want it to be a descendent of some custom class that you made.